# C++ double division and return

Tags: c++, floating-point

I understand that doubles are only approximations. But I was surprised that

```
double f(int x, int y)
{
    return double(x)/y;
}
```

and

```
double f(int x, int y)
{
    double z = double(x)/y;
    return z;
}
```

can return different values. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you have an example of that happening?

Comment: Post a complete test case with description of your problem.

Comment: [I've helped you on your way to posting an example that shows](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4igUk5$1) the problem.

Comment: if there is no pic, it din't happen

Comment: Hard to believe in this. What compiler, flags and OS and kernel OS and processor do you use?

Comment: @TonyTheLion Your example doesn't show the problem.  The problem depends on when the compiler truncates an intermediate value with greater precision to a double.  In your code, the value will be rounded to double when calling `<<`, even if it hadn't been rounded before.

Comment: @sftrabbit I've seen the problem happen in a comparison function for `std::sort`.  The comparison returned something like `lhs.f() < rhs.f()`, and returned true when `lhs` and `rhs` were references to the same object (which ultimately caused `std::sort` to access out of bounds, and crashed the program).

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious I've seen it on Intel architectures, with g++, at least (but I think VC++ behaves similarly).

Comment: @JamesKanze, I know it doesn't show the problem, I was merely encouraging OP to create an example that creates the problem

Comment: FFIW, with VC++, you may have to specify `/arch:IA32` for the problem to occur.

Comment: Or `/arch:SSE2` to make it go away.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious I can reproduce the problem with x86(32-bit) MinGW gcc 4.6.2 if I compile [this test](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1gbOw9$18) with `gcc -std=gnu89 fpdiff.c -o fpdiff.exe -O0`. I can't seem to reproduce it with online compilers. On my PC it fails test 2.

Comment: "doubles are only approximations" is not true. They have well-defined, precise semantics. **Conversion** from text to double usually results in an approximation, but that's not significantly different from converting, say, 1.2 to an `int`; the primary difference is that programmers have been taught from infancy how integer arithmetic works, and have internalized its quirks, but have generally **not** been taught how floating-point arithmetic works, so resort to "it's approximate" or "it's random" to justify seeing results they didn't expect. (That said, the problem discussed here is real)

Comment: @PeteBecker I think the reason most programmers say that "doubles are only approximations" is that they assume the abstraction for `double` is real numbers.  (As abstractions go, `double` is a pretty poor abstraction of real numbers, given that most of the usual properties, like associativeness, don't hold.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - you give programmers credit for far more understanding than I do.

Answer (score 7):

The main reason "why" is that the standard allows it (except
that I'm not 100% sure that it does).  The pragmatic reason is
that on some processors (including Intel 32 bit processors),
floating point registers have more precision than a `double`.
Intermediate calculations are done in the registers, if they fit
(and the standard clearly allows intermediate results to have
more precision), so the results of any given expression will
depend on how the compiler manages its registers, and when it
spills to memory.  And many (most?) compilers for such
processors will return floating point values in a register, 
where they keep the extra precision.  (I'm not sure that this is
legal.  When assigning a double, and I think when copy
constructing a double, the value must be made to fit.  Returning
a value is copy construction, so I think it should force the
double to fit.  Regardless... most compilers don't so you have
to deal with it, regardless of what the standard might or might
not have to say about it.)

I think you can prevent this by explicitly casting the final
results, i.e.:

```
return double( double(x)/y );
```

, but I'm not sure (neither about what the standard says about
it, nor about what compilers actually do).

Note that whether the results are different or not depends
somewhat on what you do with them.  If you immediately assign
them to a `double`, or pass them to another function which
requires a `double`, then all that happens is that the rounding
occurs a little later (but still on the same value).  If you use
the value in an expression, however, all bets are off.   In your
case, `2.0 * f( a, b )` might result in a different value
depending on your implementation of `f`, even after rounding.
And most noticeably, `f( a, b ) == f( a, b )` may return false.
(I've seen a case where this caused `std::sort` to crash.  The
comparison function used did something along the lines of
`return lhs.f() < rhs.f();`, and was returning `true` when `lhs`
and `rhs` were references to the same object; the compiler spilled the results of the first function it called to memory, then did the comparison with the value in the register which the second function returned.)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of that this is going to happen is with an optimizing compiler on an x87 FPU. The x87 FPU uses long double precision, so that values in registers can be held with more precision than values in double variables on the stack. It's at least conceivable that an optmising compiler given the above code might use a register for the return value in one case and the stack for the other.

But I would like to see a real example.

Comment: It's almost certainly a case of the x87 FPU.  And it's not that the compiler returns one in a floating point register, the other in an actual `double`; it's that the compiler enforces the rule that the returned value must be that contained in the variable (which has been rounded to `double`), either reading what it just wrote to return it, or explicitly forcing the rounding on the value in the FPU.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the methods, and I made a simple test, calling both of them.
The values are simply [as aspected] equal.
Here's two options:
1) You're making a false question. [I don't think so!]
2) The compiler makes more implicit casts when you "store" the value in z, reducing the precision of the variable.
The problem can be also the way you pass the value.
In fact, in many languages, if you get `.5` [E.G. float = .5] by assignment, it will be more precise that making a division [E.G. `float z = 1 / 2;`]